# gcloud deployment: unable to change dnsconfig (DNSConfig: custom pod DNS is disabled by feature gate)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I´m trying to set an additional nameserver for a deployment on gcloud Kubernetes like this:

```
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
    - 172.16.248.32
    searches:
    - ns1.svc.cluster.local
    - mynetwork.local
    options:
    - name: ndots
      value: "2"
    - name: edns0
```

This fails with the following error:

> spec.template.spec.dnsConfig: Forbidden: DNSConfig: custom pod DNS is
>   disabled by feature gate

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question:

Update to 1.10.9-gke.0 fixed this issue.

Afterwards I spun up an DNS Machine in the cluster with bind9 in order to be able to route `cluster.local` hostnames inside the cluster and `mycompany.local` to the company dns.

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit of background on why:

> spec.template.spec.dnsConfig: Forbidden: DNSConfig: custom pod DNS is disabled by feature gate

Starting with Kubernetes 1.10 the `CustomPodDNS` feature became beta and enabled by default. You would have had to add [`--feature-gates=CustomPodDNS=true`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) to the kube-apiserver and kubelets for this to work on Kubernetes 1.9 and earlier:

[image: header]
[image: feature gate]